# I installed bitcoin core and it started synchronising, at 50 % it says that i dont have enough free disk space

Tags: blockchain, network, synchronization

How is it possible that i don't have enough free space? I checked beforehand and the client said i needed around 120GB but i have at least 290GB free space and now it says at 50% that my disk is full and so it quit.

Comment: a bit more information would help to support this type of question. Windows, Linux, MacOS, what version of Core client, how you come to say that 50% is full, where the 290 GB come from...

Comment: -1 The likely answer would be that your free space is not on the same partition as the bitcoin directory. If that's not the answer, please edit your question to rule that out.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is not an issue with bitcoin but the software implement.

I suggest check whether you choose data directory at proper disk partition.